# Python Django | view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-urls, django-authentication

> File "\app\urls.py", line 10, in 
>       name='login'),
>   File "\django\conf\urls__init__.py", line 85, in url
>       raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().') TypeError: view must be a callable or a
>   list/tuple in the case of include().

urls.py

> ```
>     urlpatterns = [
>     # previous login view
>     # url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
>     # login / logout urls
>     url(r'^login/$',
>         'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
>         name='login'),
>     url(r'^logout/$',
>         'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
>         name='logout'),
>     url(r'^logout-then-login/$',
>         'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',
>         name='logout_then_login'),
> ]
> ```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
                                password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
                  'account/dashboard.html',
                  {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String reference is deprecated in Django 1.10.

```
import django.contrib.auth.views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login, name='login'),
    ...
]
```